# Android/Linux thread join with timeout

Tags: android, linux, multithreading, timer, pthread-join

Is there a pthreads API call that can do something simlar to `pthread_join()` but with a timeout?  I'm looking for a function that is similar to the Windows WaitForSingleObject(HANDLE handle, int timeout) function.  I know that there's a `pthread_timedjoin()` call, but that's only available on certain version's of Linux (definitely not in Android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no standard API for a timed pthread_join(), and not one available in the bionic C library used by Android. Though looking at the bionic source code, it'd be very easy for them to implement the pthread_timedjoin_np() API as available in glibc.

What you can do is to modify your thread to signal a pthread_cond_t when it's finished and about to exit. Your other thread that wants to wait on that thread does a pthread_cond_timedwait() on the condition variable.

Comment: Ive seen 2 solutions on the web: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/xrat/xsh_chap02.html#tag_03_02_08_21
and 
http://therealdavebarry.blogspot.com/2006/03/waiting-for-thread-pthreadjoin-with.html
The first one seems to create a special type of timed thread.  The second one..i'm not really sure.

Comment: I ended up going with the second solution.  Only problem is, I'd have to find a replacement for pthread_cancel()...

Comment: You could combine the condition variable solution with `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` [(see the POSIX manual page)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cleanup_push.html); that might let you continue to use `pthread_cancel()`.

I know this is an old answer, but it still shows up in search results for "pthread_join timeout".